# Incompatibility between babel-french and tasks

Tags: babel, incompatibility, bugs, tasks

There seems to be an incompatibility between these two packages.

Look at these two MWE:

## The right one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
\task aaa
\task! fff 
\task bbb
\task ccc
\task ddd
\task eee
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## The wrong one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
\task aaa
\task! fff 
\task bbb
\task ccc
\task ddd
\task eee
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- This post is to report this incompatibility
- Does someone have an nice idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't call this "solving", but you can use `etoolbox`'s `\AtBeginEnvironment` hook to deactivate the `!` inside the `tasks` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tasks}{\catcode`\!12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
\task aaa
\task! fff
\task bbb
\task ccc
\task ddd
\task eee
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to keep the active `!` then you can use a more brute-force approach and change the character used to denote a full-line task. For instance with `+`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__tasks_read_item:www
  {
    \peek_meaning_remove:NTF + % <-- Character to activate a full-line task
      {
        \bool_set_true:N \l__tasks_item_full_line_bool
        \__tasks_read_item_aux:ww
      }
      {
        \peek_meaning_remove:NTF *
          {
            \bool_set_true:N \l__tasks_item_rest_of_line_bool
            \__tasks_read_item_rest_of_line:ww
          }
          { \__tasks_read_item_aux:ww }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
\task aaa
\task+ fff
\task bbb
\task ccc
\task ddd
\task eee
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

---

After some digging:

jfbu suggested using `\expandafter\task\string!` or defining a `\taskexclam` to be `\task <the character !>`.

These don't work because `tasks` uses `\task` as a dummy control sequence to split the collected contents of the environment. So internally this:

```
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task aaa
\expandafter\task\string! fff
\task bbb
\taskexclam ccc
\task eee
\end{tasks}
```

is transformed into the list:

```
{ aaa \expandafter }
{ \string! fff }
{ bbb \taskexclam ccc }
{ eee }
```

which makes the `\expandafter` trick useless and the `\string!` will simply write a `!`. The `\taskexclam` is also executed too late, so it has no effect.

An approach that obeys `tasks`' rules and preserves the meaning of `!` in french is copying the character definition of `!` before loading `babel` then using the new name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\exclam=!

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
\task aaa
\task\exclam fff
\task bbb
\task ccc
\task ddd
\task eee
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately `tasks` seems to be gathering its contents because `\expandafter\task\string!` fails...

Comment: and for same reason it seems impossible to use `\taskexclam` in place of `\task!` with `\taskexclam` defined to expand to `\task <catcode twelve !>`. So `task` package makes it hard to work around that problem if not using your approach which however has the problem that `!` in items will not be correctly typeset for French.

Comment: @jfbu Good point... Indeed, `tasks` uses `environ`'s `\NewEnviron` to collect the contents of the environment. It then uses `\peek_meaning_remove:NTF` to check for the `!`. One would have to trick this test to get it working with the active `!`...

Comment: maybe OP should send a Feature Request to `tasks` for either allow active `!` or allow to specify another character for that job... or allow some `\taskfullwidth` in place of `\task!`.

Comment: Thanks for your interest for this issue. I have opened an issue on the `github` page of the `tasks` package.

Comment: @jfbu Searching a bit further in the code of `tasks` I found out that `\taskexclam` and `\expandafter\task\string!` don't work because the package uses `\task` not as a command, like `\item` but as a separator for `\seq_set_split:Nnn`, so `\taskexclam` gets executed only at the proper typesetting stage, and belongs to the previous item, and `\expandafter\task\string!` puts the `\expandafter` in a separate item than `\string!`. Using `\let\exclam=!` before loading `babel` and using `\task\exclam` seems like a better approach, though.

Comment: good investigation, thanks for explaining! `\let\exclam!` and `\task\exclam` is good way!